# Daisy chaining ungrounded LED, what do with last ground wire?

Tags: electrical, lighting, grounding

I’m daisy chaining 4 LEDs that aren’t grounded and was wondering what to do with the last ground wire. For the first 3 LEDs, I connected the grounds with a wire nut (see picture). What should I do with the ground wire for the last LED where there will only have a single 14/2 wire coming in? Cap it with a wire nut?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no grounds on the fixtures, just leave the ground wire unconnected and in the enclosure.  Personally, I would cap it with a small wire nut to prevent it from working its way into the connectors. The ground wire is connected at the other end, right?

Comment: Yes, the source of the first LED is grounded to a jonction box and eventually to the electric panel. That’s what I thought to put a wire nut on the last ground wire.